# Why is the default value of my ion-select not being displayed?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

So I have a Ion-select with 3 static values and I would like for the 2nd one to be selected and displayed by default, doesn't sound to difficult or much of a problem right? Well so I tried simply adding selected near the ion-select option (displayed in the code below) just like they did with the example on the [official document](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-docs/blob/master/src/demos/api/select/index.html), but that for some reason had absolutely no effect and it is still not being displayed when I reload the page. Any idea on what could be the problem here?

```
<ion-item>
     <ion-label>{{ "HOME.row_text" | translate }}</ion-label>
     <ion-select [(ngModel)]="drive_option" (ionChange)="updateResult()"> 
          <ion-select-option value=0.5>{{ "HOME.row_half" | translate }}</ion-select-option>
          <ion-select-option value=1 selected>{{ "HOME.row_simple" | translate }}</ion-select-option>
          <ion-select-option value=2>{{ "HOME.row_double" | translate }}</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 1):

The matching between the model value and the dom value is type sensitive.

Vanilla dom properties are always strings and won't match the numeric `drive_option`. Try:

```
<ion-select-option [value]="0.5">{{ "HOME.row_half" | translate }}</ion-select-option>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because `selected` doesn't mean anything when you are using `ngModel`.

You need to set `drive_option = 1` in the code and it will be reflected in the UI.

You probably don't need that `(ionChange)` either as any change will automatically update the `drive_option` value.

It would be helpful for you to go through the Angular documentation to understand how things work.

It was confusing for me too at the start (and still is regularly) but Ionic is not just about using Ionic, you need to take some time to get a core understand of Angular as well.

The concept is though that you are not building a traditional form, you are building a data model, and then letting angular two way bind that data - which is what the `[()]` means.

Comment: drive_option is already being set to 1 at the start of the app. So no that didn't solve the problem.